# Forming 4 teams of 15 players out of a set of 60

Tags: probability, combinatorics

[image]

Why isn't it just $${60\choose 15} \times {45\choose 15} \times {30\choose 15} \times {15\choose 15}$$  I really don't get this problem.

Comment: did you evaluate your answer ?

Comment: yup but it ended up not equaling my professor's answer.

Comment: you are differentiating the teams so you need to divide by 4!

Comment: btw last term of your expression should be $15C15$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer assumes you pick $15$ players for the first team, then pick $15$ from the remaining for the second team, and so on.  This would be fine if the first team got red jerseys, the second blue, the third green, and the fourth black, and we cared about which team had which color jerseys.  There is nothing in the problem to indicate that, so there are $4!$ orders we can pick the same teams.  It is like we picked the teams as above, then allowed them to swap jerseys.  There are $4!$ ways the jerseys can be swapped, so we have to divide by that.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy case that  that you can try by listing the possibilities: Take a set of 4 persons and find how many ways you can form 2 teams of 2 persons from them.
{AB,CD}, {AC,BD}, {AD,BC}. Thats all, it is not ${4\choose 2}$. This will make you realise and arrive at the formula yourself.